# Alternating ciphers (block cipher and stream cipher)

Tags: security, encryption, cryptography, aes, credit-card

I am reviewing the code for a product our team developed where credit card information is stored in a local database. This database can be accessed in the event of no internet connection. I came across the encryption methods.

The developer who wrote this portion of our code encrypted AES over RABBIT over AES. I have seen implementations with AES over AES (same concept I suppose as Triple DES) but I've never seen or researched stacking block over stream. I don't know if the results from this are going to be consistent (i.e. without data corruption) or secure.

I would assume they would be because I assume stacking encryption with different keys can never be less secure than one time encryption. Below is a sample of the code I found.

```js
function classSecureMessage(message){
 this.secretA=security.randomAlphaNum(56);
 this.secretB=security.randomAlphaNum(56);
 this.secretC=security.randomAlphaNum(56);
 var passStr=message;
 passStr=CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(passStr, this.secretA);
 passStr=CryptoJS.Rabbit.encrypt(passStr.toString(), this.secretB);
 passStr=CryptoJS.AES.encrypt(passStr.toString(), this.secretC);
 this.message=passStr; 
 this.decrypt= function(){
  var passStr=CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(this.message, this.secretC).toString( CryptoJS.enc.Utf8 );
  passStr=CryptoJS.Rabbit.decrypt(passStr, this.secretB).toString( CryptoJS.enc.Utf8 );
  passStr=CryptoJS.AES.decrypt(passStr, this.secretA).toString( CryptoJS.enc.Utf8 );
  return(passStr);
 }
}
```

EDIT: To add the performance of this is not horrible. it takes 0.012 seconds to encrypt and decrypt credit card data.

Comment: That kind of solution might get your company out of business and make a lot of people unhappy. It's forbidden to store credit card information if you are to be a VISA or Mastercard merchant.

Comment: @DarkWander It is not forbidden to store credit card information. But you will have to be PCI certified ..

Comment: @DarkWanderer No there guidelines specifically state that credit card information if stored must be encrypted with a "strong" cryptographic algorithm to meet or exceed the standards set forth in AES128. and in no condition can the entire track data be stored. This is standard procedures for nearly every POS system on the market to take the information and store it when it is unable to process it immediately.

Comment: @EbbeM.Pedersen we are fully PCI compliant, been audited by firstData(our preffered gateway service) and have had 3rd party PCI Compliance and Risk Assesments performed.

Comment: Okay, I stand corrected. I do hope  the secrets are stored in different locations then (as AES over AES can only make sense then)

Comment: @DarkWanderer the keys are stored in local memory of the POS terminal while the card data is held on a SQL server on the local network. I have used AES over AES in many instances before just never seen something with a encrypting with both block and stream before.

Comment: What is your actual question; is this secure?

Comment: @MaartenBodewes yes. Asking if it is secure. Or more specifically if it offers much if any additional security over AES

Comment: AES is thought to be secure against all attacks, AES-256 doubly so. So in the best case this adds a tremendous amount of complexity and overhead without any benefits. Did you know it probably uses an OpenSSL proprietary KDF to calculate the keys, for instance? It's probably not insecure though, but it would be hell to replicate in e.g. another language. Without protocol description and security analysis it should never have passed inspection regardless of anything else.

Comment: I recently took this project over. The documentation from the last developer simply lists AES128 as the encryption method.

Comment: Using passwords instead of keys raises serious questions about key management. I also wonder how/when the keys are stored. That's a bigger issue than the stacked encryption. I'm also wondering what the random number generator would be with this homebrew encryption scheme. The number of bits extracted from it would be at least 280 bits per key, but that makes little difference if it is insecure.

Comment: If it lists AES-128 then it is seriously out of sync with the implementation. AES-128 is not even used, CryptoJS lists AES-256 as used for password encryption. This should not be acceptable development practice for security related components.

Comment: The random numbers are generated through a 3rd party cryptography library in javascript. The keys are generated when the system attempts to run a credit card that fails due to network failure. These keys are then stored on the local machine while the cc data is stored on a sql server on the local network.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes alright so, would I be best to scrap the existing encryption schema and go with CryptoJs's aes256 and implement a better key generator? And of course update our documents on protocols and storage mediums

Comment: Yes, and delete this question. Too much information here. You should be at yellow alert phase and inform management. Probably better not to mention SO :)

Comment: Thank you sir! Not sure how this slipped through like this.  In relatively new to pci dss. Well delete this when I get back to my computer.  Can't seem to find the delete button on the app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a reference to having a block-stream-block cypher [here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5744/double-encrypting-with-two-different-keys), which mentions Bruce Schneier's book Applied Cryptography.

I've never seen stacking of the same cypher as (as it says on the link) the idea is that each party trusts a different cypher... so there's no added security in stacking AES over AES, except in the case of a brute force attack.

I would swap one of the AES cyphers with another block cypher, so in the case that one of the 2 ciphers is compromised, your data will still be secure.